# Modify the Docker image and save it for not loose the content when building the container again. How?

Tags: image, docker, containers, commit, ros

Hi I need to modify the a docker image from Autoware_AI repository after build it. The problem is:

A) I build the image running a .sh file:

```
cd $WORKING_DIRECTORY/docker/generic
./run.sh -t 1.14.0
```

It is specifically from Autoware: https://www.svlsimulator.com/docs/system-under-test/autoware-instructions/

B) I modify the scripts contained inside the packages contained in Autoware folder

C) When I exit the container, and later enter again the modifications are not there anymore, of coure, because the image is built from Dockerfile from scratch...

To find a solution I have tried 2 different approachs:

1. To modify the container and save it as described here: https://www.scalyr.com/blog/create-docker-image/

Issue: When  using other terminal, trying to add .txt file for Autoware_AI running container, to modify the container, Autoware_AI container does not appear as active (but it is). Just other container are avaialable when I try to copy a file to Autoware_AI:

2. Commit Changes To a Docker image: https://phoenixnap.com/kb/how-to-commit-changes-to-docker-image

Issue: Problem to connect to Autoware_AI server and run the ros packages. This problem does not happen when building the original Docker file with .sh

The complete description of my problem as well as output of terminal attempts are better described here:

https://answers.ros.org/question/376512/fork-autoware_ai-repository-and-create-docker-image/?answer=376583#post-id-376583

https://get-help.robotigniteacademy.com/t/fork-autoware-ai-repository-and-create-docker-image/9533/4

I am kind of new in forking,changing docker images. I do not understand how to fix this, find a solution for create my custom docker image and make it functional.

Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: A specific code example of what you're trying to modify would be very helpful.  Abstractly, you'd need to create a Dockerfile that starts `FROM` the image you're trying to modify, makes the required changes, and produces a new derived image.  `docker commit` is almost never a best practice (in particular you have no record of how to repeat the modifications if the base image changes).

Comment: @DavidMaze the issue in my case is that Dockerfile calls an url that contains several urls to dowload the ROS modules. For that, it is possible to fork the github links, but I would need to change the url: raw.githubusercontent.com/Autoware-AI/autoware.ai/1.14.0/… content. However I don't know how to modify a web page and save it into a new web page address. Or even create a web page from scratch with the extesion: "autoware.ai.repos" . I know how to create with the .html in a local to open with the browser. Some suggestion? I put this attempt in answer below...

Answer (score 0):

As David Maze suggested one feasible way would be change the Dockerfile, and then build my image from it. It is a good idea. In my case however additional steps were required, because I had a build.sh script that called different Dockerfiles to build the image, and besides that this build.sh file also installed some ROS packages and other dependencies.

Even if the build.sh needed to change. The modifications on Dockerfile contributed to solve 90% of the issue. My Dockerfile was:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qh3L5.png)

And After the modification, the Dockerfile became:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y6ecK.png)

To dowload the modified ROS codes to my image, instead of autoware repo ROS pkgs, I needed:

1 - Copy the autoware.ai.repos file from here:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Autoware-AI/autoware.ai/1.14.0/autoware.ai.repos
To my docker local folder (docker/generic) and unwrap them with vcs import command as the Dockerfile displays above...

2- Edit the autoware.ai.repos, in order to change the address of some of the repositories contained in autoware.ai.repos to my personal github:

I Removed the lines:

```
autoware/visualization:
    type: git
    url: https://github.com/Autoware-AI/visualization.git
    version: 1.14.0
```

And replaced by:

```
autoware/visualization:
    type: git
    url: https://github.com/marcusvinicius178/visualization
```

Afterwards I followed the build instructions in case 3 here: https://github.com/Autoware-AI/autoware.ai/wiki/Generic-x86-Docker#run-an-autoware-docker-container

$ ./build.sh

$ ./run.sh -t local

I know that may exist a more professional way to work with Docker images, and build a new Dockerfile based on the original one. But I am not that expert in Docker and also in this way my problem was solved.